# How to expand an array to a matrix

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

Iam Writing a program that takes as input, the dimension n of an array. After that enter the elements of the array. Create a function that creates and returns an n-by-n matrix with this definition:

```
int** expand(int n, int* v);
```

Here's what I want to Implement into my function expand. It should:

1. dynamically allocate an integer matrix of the given size (n x n)
2. copy the contents of the original array (v) to the newly dynamically allocated array;
3. return a pointer to the copy.
4. The main function should print out the matrix with the contents of the array in each column of
   the matrix.
5. The program should execute until it receives an EOF.

Here is what I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 4 //This is just an example, my array is supposed to be of arbitrary size

int** expand(int n, int* v);


int main ()
{
    int n;
    int arr[MAX];
    int** copy;
    while(scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
        copy = expand(n, arr);
            
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {   
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                printf("%d", copy[i]);
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf(" \n");        
        }
        free(copy);
    }
}


int** expand(int n, int* v)
{
    int** copy = calloc(n*n, sizeof(int));

    if (copy == NULL)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        copy[i] = v;
    }
    
    return copy;
}
```

So My implementation of the main looks okay and everything seems working except for my expand function and I think the issue is that im returning a pointer to a pointer of copy, which then points to a garbage value. Because when i type in input

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

my Output comes out like this:

```
-2105541888 -2105541888 -2105541888 -2105541888  
-2105541888 -2105541888 -2105541888 -2105541888
-2105541888 -2105541888 -2105541888 -2105541888
-2105541888 -2105541888 -2105541888 -2105541888
```

When my output should come out like this:

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

Im guessing that as mentioned before, my (** copy) that I allocated is pointing to a garbage value and not pointing to the value I want.

Any kind of help would very appreciated. Thank you for your time.
<3

Comment: Review `int** copy; ...  printf("%d", copy[i]);`.  `copy[i]` is a _pointer_.  `"%d"` expects an `int`.  Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: Im sorry, im new to programming. Can you explain to me how exactly can i enable all compiler warnings? I only get like red lines and green lines under my code.

Comment: "explain to me how exactly can i enable all compiler warnings?" --> It depends on the compiler (name, version) and maybe the environment (OS, tool, etc.) you are using.  Without knowing  that, hard to be _exact_.

Comment: I use gcc on vscode, and c/c++ extension.

Comment: With `gcc`, I found `'-pedantic-errors' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wconversion'` enabled many useful warnings.